# UserDefinedType Cannot be Converted to a UdtValue in Spring Data Cassandra

Tags: spring-boot, cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

I want to pass the "address" as a object in postman for the field address, like that:

```
{
    "orderOfferingDiscount": 0.0,
    "orderProducts": [
        {
            "productOfferingId": "2150f1e1-b769-446a-b870-cfdf0d071c2a"
        },
        {
            "productOfferingId": "2150f1e1-b769-446a-b870-cfdf0d071c2a"
        }
    ],
    "orderOfferingQuantity": 1,
    "customer": "81394cdc-73b0-4351-b21c-f893a4e472fe",
    "address": {
        "id": null,
        "street": "test",
        "addressNumber": 1,
        "zipCode": "123123",
        "country": "SE"
    }
}
```

So I have created the UserDefinedType for address like that:

```
@UserDefinedType("address_type")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class AddressType {

    private UUID id;

    private String street;

    private Integer addressNumber;

    private String zipCode;

    private String country;
    
}
```

And in the Order class:

```
@Table(value = "order")
@Data
public class Order {

    @Id
    @PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "order_offering_id", ordinal = 0, type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
    @CassandraType(type = Name.UUID)
    private UUID orderOfferingId;

    @Column("order_instant_date")
    @CassandraType(type = Name.DATE)
    private LocalDate orderOfferingInstanDate;

    @Column("order_discount")
    @CassandraType(type = Name.DOUBLE)
    private Double orderOfferingDiscount;

    @CassandraType(type = Name.SET, typeArguments = { Name.UDT }, userTypeName = "product_offering_type")
    private Set<ProductOfferingType> orderProducts;

    @Column("order_quantity")
    @CassandraType(type = Name.INT)
    private Integer orderOfferingQuantity;

    @Column("order_total_price")
    @CassandraType(type = Name.DOUBLE)
    private Double orderOfferingTotalPrice;

    @CassandraType(type = Name.UUID)
    private UUID customer;

    @CassandraType(type = Name.UDT, userTypeName = "address_type")
    private AddressType address;

}
```

And in the application.yml:

```
spring:
  data:
    cassandra:
      port: 9042
      contact-points: mycassandra
      keyspace-name: mykeyspace
      entity-base-package: com.cassandra.rampup.model
      schema-action: RECREATE
      request:
        timeout: 10s
      connection:
        connect-timeout: 10s
        init-query-timeout: 10s
      converters:
        entity-to-udt-packages: com.cassandra.rampup.model
        udt-to-entity-packages: com.cassandra.rampup.CassandraUserTypes
```

But when I try to post a order in my api endpoint it's returns this:

```
"message": "No converter found capable of converting from type [com.cassandra.rampup.CassandraUserTypes.AddressType] to type [com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.data.UdtValue]"
```

I tried to create a converter for this, but it does not work

Comment: Hi, Victor, welcome to StackOverlow! I tihink this link can help you: https://itecnote.com/tecnote/spring-user-defined-type-with-spring-data-cassandra/ .